# Javascript/jQuery if Select list value contains a value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using Javascript/jQuery, I want compare to see if a selected value from a Select list contains a value from an array.

As you will see below, the array values are only part of the Select option value.  I need to compare to see if the selected option value contains a value of 'myArr'.

My current code is:

```js
var myArr = ["10:00", "10:20", "10:40"];

    //Currently not working

$('select').on('change', function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).text(), myArr)){
     console.log("YES in array")
     }else{
    console.log("NOT in array")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
     <option value="43987">9:00 AM - 21 Available</option>
     <option value="43988">9:20 AM - 33 Available</option>
     <option value="43997">9:40 AM - 40 Available</option>     
     <option value="43990">10:00 AM - 10 Available</option>
     <option value="43991">10:20 AM - 6 Available</option>
     <option value="43992">10:40 AM - 22 Available</option>
     <option value="43993">11:00 AM - 80 Available</option>
    </select>
```

EDIT:
I updated the post to not look at the value but if the 'text' is contained in the array.  I don't have an option ot use the value because we post process that value as an ID to do some matching.  This is why I need to know if the option 'text' is contained in the array.

Comment: The values of the options do not match those in the array.  `inArray` does not consider partial matches.  It only considers exact matches.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to actually put `value="9:00"` attributes on your options.

Comment: @Taplar, right now I don't have that option.  The values are the way they are needing.  I am updating my question because a quanityte might be part of the "Available."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myArr = ["10:00", "10:20", "10:40"];

$('select').on('change', function() {
  const time = this.value.split(' ')[0];
  
  if($.inArray(time, myArr) > -1) {
    console.log('In Array');
  } else {
    console.log('Not In Array');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>9:00 AM - Available</option>
  <option>9:20 AM - Available</option>
  <option>9:40 AM - Available</option>
  <option>10:00 AM - Available</option>
  <option>10:20 AM - Available</option>
  <option>10:40 AM - Available</option>
  <option>11:00 AM - Available</option>
</select>
```

If you do not want to change the value, then grab the selected option, string off the leading time, and use that in your inArray call.

Edit: You actually don't need the option.  Just the value.

Comment: Works great, great solution.  Simple.  Thank you.  Of course the split().

Comment: So, this works if the option does not have a 'value=' property. I updated my question to add a 'value=' property with various IDs.  I actually need to compare the text.  When I tried using the $(this).text().split(' ' )[0]; That did not work. Is there anyway to compare the text value with the array value?

Comment: That would be my previous version that used `var $option = $('option:selected', this); var time = $option.text().split(' ')[0];` @ClosDesign

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have correct value attribute that would be an exact match with those that are in array. So simply add value attribute for each options. I also used js `includes()` method of the array to check exactly what you tried, but with jQuery

```js
var myArr = ["10:00", "10:20", "10:40"];

    //Currently not working

$('select').on('change', function(){
    if(myArr.includes($(this).val())){
     console.log("YES in array")
     }else{
    console.log("NOT in array")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
     <option value="9:00">9:00 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="9:20">9:20 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="9:40">9:40 AM - Available</option>     
     <option value="10:00">10:00 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="10:20">10:20 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="10:40">10:40 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="11:00">11:00 AM - Available</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: My apologies, I updated the Post, the value is not possible because we do some post processing based on an ID that we populate with the value.  I need to know if the 'text' in the option is contained in the array.

Comment: Then yeah there is an alternative way to get the selected value which was used in @Taplar answer

Comment: So I tried getting the value, but I updated my question and added values to the ID,  I ended up testing @Taplar's example, which worked when I did not have a 'value=' property on the option values, but once I added the 'value=' property, Taplar's solution does not work. So I tried the jQuery .text() instead.  But that returned False on all selections.

Answer (score 0):

just try to use method includes(). [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var myArr = ["10:00", "10:20", "10:40"];

$('select').on('change', function(){

    if(myArr.includes($(this).val())){
     console.log("YES in array")
     }else{
    console.log("NOT in array")
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
     <option value="9:00">9:00 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="9:20">9:20 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="9:40">9:40 AM - Available</option>     
     <option value="10:00">10:00 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="10:20">10:20 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="10:40">10:40 AM - Available</option>
     <option value="11:00">11:00 AM - Available</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my solution!

```js
var myArr = ["10:00 AM - 10 Available", "10:20 AM - 6 Available", "10:40"];

    //Currently not working

$('select').on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var textSelected   = optionSelected.text();

    if(myArr.includes(textSelected)){
     console.log("YES in array")
     }else{
    console.log("NOT in array")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
     <option value="43987">9:00 AM - 21 Available</option>
     <option value="43988">9:20 AM - 33 Available</option>
     <option value="43997">9:40 AM - 40 Available</option>     
     <option value="43990">10:00 AM - 10 Available</option>
     <option value="43991">10:20 AM - 6 Available</option>
     <option value="43992">10:40 AM - 22 Available</option>
     <option value="43993">11:00 AM - 80 Available</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about split the value into an array of words first. then use the includes method

```js
var myArr = ["10:00", "10:20", "10:40"];
$('select').on('change', function(){
let inArray = false
$(this).val().split(" ").forEach((element) => {
     if(myArr.includes(element)){
     inArray = true
    }
  });  
  if(inArray){
  console.log("YES in array")
  }else{
  console.log("NOT in array")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
     <option>9:00 AM - Available</option>
     <option>9:20 AM - Available</option>
     <option>9:40 AM - Available</option>     
     <option>10:00 AM - Available</option>
     <option>10:20 AM - Available</option>
     <option>10:40 AM - Available</option>
     <option>11:00 AM - Available</option>
    </select>
```